Laravel Fingerprint Enrollment and matching with UareU 4500 device
I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to implement a fingerprint-based attendance system. I have a U.are.U 4500 fingerprint reader and I'm new to biometrics. I would like to get ideas how to integrate fingerprint enrollment and verification/matching into my Laravel application. What is the best approach to integrate fingerprint functionality with Laravel? Should I use a separate service or library?
i chanced on this repo https://github.com/shanxp/fingerprint-digital-persona-u-are-u-4500-web-examplewhich works for the capture but does not have the feature of verification/matching.
i also tried following this tutorial but didn't quite get that.
https://hidglobal.github.io/digitalpersona-devices/tutorial.html
